# Access server on raspberry pi on local network

Tags: server, rust, raspberry-pi, lan, raspberry-pi4

I am running a server on my raspberry pi (rpi) on `port 8088`.

The server is rust/actix and I run it with `cargo run`.

I ssh into the rpi with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` and I run `curl localhost:8088`. The server returns 200 OK and an index.html file. As expected.

I use `hostname -I` to find the IP address of the rpi `192.168.0.25` and this one `172.17.0.1`.

When I go to another device on the same local network and run `curl 192.168.0.25:8088` or `curl raspberrypi.local:8088` I get *ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*

If I run `curl 172.17.0.1:8088` I get *ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT*

How do I access the server running on my raspberry pi from another machine on my local network?

Comment: Firewall? / Port Forwarding?

Comment: You can bind to a specific address in `actix_web::HttpServer` using `.bind("192.168.0.25:8088")` maybe this will help.

Comment: @zgerd Thanks, that worked! I forgot I bound it to localhost -.-

Comment: use 0.0.0.0 instead of hard-coded 192.168.0.25 to avoid issues in the future (when router assigns new IP to RPi via DHCP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answers in the comments I noticed I had bound the ip to `localhost`.

By binding it to `0.0.0.0`, the problem got fixed and I can access the server externally